# On the xfp package: ternary operator x ? y : z

Tags: xfp

On page 1/2 [xfp package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfp.pdf) we see `ternary operator x ? y : z` as a valid boolean expression. it deserves the author puts at least the definition of this.
In C I was told we have:

> `variable = Expression1 ? Expression2 : Expression3` is equivalent to
> `if(Expression1) { variable = Expression2;} else {variable = Expression3;}.`

To check the validity of the definition above I wrote a code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}
\edef\x{6.25}
\edef\y{-1}
\edef\z {{\x > \y} ? {\x} :{ \y}}
$(x>y)?x:y=\fpeval{\z}$
\end{document}
```

But got an error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \__fp_parse_continue:NwN.
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: +1 I really like your questions, they move me forward. :-)

Comment: @ AndréC: Thanks!

Comment: You can't use curly braces to group terms.  Use parentheses, i.e. `\edef\z{(\x > \y) ? (\x) : (\y)}`

Comment: BTW, `{x > y} ? {x} :{y}` also doesn't compile in C. https://wandbox.org/permlink/AfzIMPvpyhwgno8K

Comment: @ Henri Menke: Great Answer!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: `\fpeval` and `\inteval` in `xfp` package are just wrappers of latex3 functions `\fp_eval:n` and `\int_eval:n`, which (as well as their argument, floating point expression and integer expression) are fully documented in [`texdoc interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), sec. XI.1, XXIII.2, and XXIII.9.

Comment: Why `\edef`? That’s the wrong bit to begin with.

Comment: I got the idea from fp package. Any better one?

Comment: Might you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based ternary operator (no `xfp` package required)? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `\edef` to begin with, unless you keep changing the meaning of `\x` and `\y`.

But this is not the cause of the error; braces should never be used in fp-expressions. You can freely use `(<fp-expression>)` if you're worried about the interpretation of some part in the big expression.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\def\x{6.25}
\def\y{-1}
\def\z {\x > \y ? \x : \y}

$(x>y)?x:y=\fpeval{\z}$

\def\y{6.25}
\def\z {\x >= \y ? \x+1 : \y-1}

$(x>=y)?x:y=\fpeval{\z}$

\end{document}
```

What's the difference between the following pieces of code?

```
% with \edef
\edef\x{6.25}
\edef\y{-1}
\edef\z {\x > \y ? \x : \y}

% with \def
\def\x{6.25}
\def\y{-1}
\def\z {\x > \y ? \x : \y}
```

The definition of `\x` and `\y` are unaffected. In the first case, the definition of `\z` would be

```
6.25 > -1 ? 6.25 : -1
```

in the second case it would be

```
\x > \y ? \x : \y
```

and the values of `\x` and `\y` will be replaced with the ones which are current at run time. Which is quite likely the purpose of using `\x` and `\y`.

On the other hand, I already suggested you a way to use “named variables”, which avoids quirks with short command names. The first time you use `\c` for a variable and want to cite some Turkish author in your paper, you'll understand what I mean.